# Polymer core-animation-group imperative example?

Tags: animation, polymer

I'm fairly new to Polymer and struggling to get some animations to work imperatively. My page displays a grid of cards. When one is clicked, I want the rest to move off screen.

I can get the cards to move one at a time in code, but since they all need to move in parallel, I *think* I need a core-animation-group to run them. But...

I can't figure out the syntax for creating a core-animation-group in code, and there doesn't seem to be a "play()" method...?

I'd be very, very grateful for a quick example.

TIA

Comment: Kind of depends on what you want. I haven't worked with a `core-animation-group` before, but with `core-animated-pages` you can transition between 'pages'. [Here's some examples](https://www.polymer-project.org/components/core-animated-pages/demo.html). Please clarify what you want to do and supply code you already have. As for `core-animation-group`, check out the [demo](https://www.polymer-project.org/components/core-animation/demo.html). It has a group example, also utilizing the `play()` method.

Comment: As I said, I want the clicked card to expand to full screen, with the other cards sliding off. Kinda sorta like this: http://tympanus.net/Development/FullscreenLayoutPageTransitions/ but the cards aren't the same size.

Comment: The core-animation-group demo (which I had looked at) creates the object in html, not code.I'm simply looking for a little code snippet to create and play a core-animation-group in js. 

I've tried creating an array of animations and passing the array to the group constructor, and I've tried creating the animations inside the constructor, but I can't figure out the syntax.

Answer (score 0):

The documentation on core-animation-group is a bit lackluster, but it is possible to create and play a core-animation-group using only JavaScript.  Create your core-animation-group with `new CoreAnimationGroup()`.  Then add child animations with `animGroup.appendChild(coreAnim)`.  Finally, play the group with `animGroup.play()`.

You say you want to animate an indeterminate number of cards in parallel.  Try something like this:

```js
var cards = document.querySelector("#cards-wrapper").children;

var anim = new CoreAnimationGroup();
anim.type = "par";  // Display child animations in parallel.
anim.duration = 200;  // Milliseconds

var cardAnimKeyframes = [
  // CSS properties {propName: "value"}
  {opacity: 1},
  {opacity: 0},
];

for (var i = 0; i < cards.length; i++) {
  var childAnim = new CoreAnimation();
  childAnim.target = cards[i];
  childAnim.keyframes = cardAnimKeyframes;
  anim.appendChild(childAnim); // This is critical.
}

// Then, when you are ready...
anim.play();
```

Hope this helps :D